# How do I display my phone number in a text field in an ios iphone app

Tags: iphone

I'm very new to ios development and am trying to get my phone number to display in a text field, or something similar, without hard coding it in. Is there a way to 'call' that data from my phone and display it in a text field, Is this even possible? Thanks!

Comment: iOS does not provide an API for getting the phone number for the current device. Your app will need to get the number from the user. You could let them type it in or pick it from their contacts.

Answer (score 1):

In a UITextView (rather than a UITextField), you can set iOS to automatically detect phone numbers that can then be tapped to initiate a call,

```
textview.editable = NO;
textview.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

You can also define the detected types in IBuilder under Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

General question so a general answer:

You can get the phone number from Contacts - so have a look at what the AddressBook framework can do for you.